# problems with iterating in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

What happened here? I built a code at always the event button is pressed, he creates dynamically a popup element on the page. But whenever I presse outside the created element and pressed the event button again. He created six more pop-up elements. Anyone can help me?

```
let cardServices = [{
   content: "2° Via de Boleto",
   image: "/img/dolar.svg" 
 }, 
 {
   content: "Adiantamento de parcelas",
   image: "/img/exchange.svg" 
 }, 
 {
   content: "Quitação de Contrato",
   image: "/img/contract.svg" 
 }, 
 {
   content: "2° Via de Boleto",
   image: "/img/dolar.svg" 
 }, 
 {
   content: "Adiantamento de parcelas",
   image: "/img/exchange.svg" 
 }, 
 {
   content: "Quitação de Contrato",
   image: "/img/contract.svg" 
 }
]

const buttonAllCardServices = document.getElementById("buttonAllCardServices");
const modalContainer = document.getElementById("modal-services");
const elementCardServices = document.querySelector("#modal-services .modal");

function createAllCardServices() {
 const cardsButton = cardServices.length;
 let addedCards = 0;

 cardServices.forEach(button => {
   if( addedCards % cardsButton == 0 ) {
     elementCardServices.innerHTML += 
     `<div class="row"></div>`;
   }

   modalContainer.classList.add("show")

   const row = document.querySelector(".row:last-child");
   row.innerHTML += 
   `<div class="image-card-service image-card">
     <img src="${button.image}" class="icon" /> <h2>${button.content}</h2>
   </div>`;

   addedCards++;

 })

}

buttonAllCardServices.addEventListener("click", () => {
 createAllCardServices();
});

modalContainer.addEventListener("click", e => {
 if(e.target.id == "modal-services") {
   modalContainer.classList.remove("show");
 }
})
```

Comment: provide the  html that goes with this

Comment: where's modalContainer declared?